# dhclient configuration on FreeBSD

Tags: router, dns, freebsd

I have a FreeBSD server behind router. But after startup (I've put `ifconfig_re0="DHCP"` in my `rc.conf`) I have

> ping: cannot resolve google.com: Host name lookup failure

error when trying `ping google.com`.
I can only retrieve IP after next commands:

```
ifconfig re0 down
ifcofing re0 up 
dhclient re0
```

OUTPUT:

```
DHCPREQUEST on re0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67
DHCPACK from 192.168.19.20
bound to 192.168.19.140 -- renewal in 43200 seconds.
```

How can I fix this error and correctly configure dhcp on my machine?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the output of `ifconfig` right after startup, and `re0` doesn't show up with an IP address you might want to chack your logfiles and see if you find any messages from dhclient there.

If you get timeouts, edit `/etc/dhclient.conf` (which is empty by default) and play with the `timeout` and `initial-interval` variables. See dhclient.conf(5).